# Angular PWA hash files caching issue

Tags: angular, azure, azure-devops, service-worker, angular-service-worker

It seems that after a fresh build with azure that my PWA is serving the wrong files

Here is my `runtime.*.js` after a new build

[image]

as you can see the `runtime.*.js` is being served as my `html` document??

then after a hard refresh

[image]

its the correct file...

Now I know the service worker caches the bundled files.. but why would it change the file to be a html document after a new azure build??

This is my `ngsw-config.json`

```
{
    "index": "/index.html",
    "assetGroups": [
        {
            "name": "app",
            "installMode": "prefetch",
            "resources": {
                "files": ["/favicon.ico", "/index.html", "/manifest.json", "/*.bundle.css", "/*.bundle.js", "/*.chunk.js"]
            }
        },
        {
            "name": "assets",
            "installMode": "lazy",
            "updateMode": "prefetch",
            "resources": {
                "files": ["/assets/**", "/*.(eot|svg|cur|jpg|png|webp|gif|otf|ttf|woff|woff2|ani)"]
            }
        }
    ]
}
```

Which I have taken from numerous tutorials on how to correctly set up an Angular PWA.

I found this article https://blog.ailon.org/quick-tip-pwa-manifest-and-azure-dd16664a3f43 and it tells you that azure incorrectly serves `.json` files and to remedy this you can do the following in you `web.config`

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<configuration>
  <system.webServer>
    <staticContent>
      <mimeMap fileExtension=".json" mimeType="application/json" />
    </staticContent>
    <!-- IIS URL Rewrite for Angular routes -->
    <rewrite>
      <rules>
        <rule name="Angular Routes" stopProcessing="true">
          <match url=".*" />
          <conditions logicalGrouping="MatchAll">
            <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" matchType="IsFile" negate="true" />
            <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" matchType="IsDirectory" negate="true" />
            <add input="{REQUEST_URI}" pattern="^/(api)" negate="true" />
          </conditions>
          <action type="Rewrite" url="/index.html" />
        </rule>
      </rules>
    </rewrite>
  </system.webServer>
</configuration>
```

but I am still getting this happen on every new build from azure

What am I doing wrong? Is this the service worker? or is it a problem with azure?

This is my azure pipeline

[image]

and this is my release pipeline

[image]

How can I solve this issue??

Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: Could you share more information about how the project is built? In azure devops build pipeline or visual studio? any build configurations?

Comment: @LeviLu-MSFT yes the project is built with the azure devops build pipeline - I have edited my question with the pipline config

Comment: I created a simple pwa project by following [this tutorial](https://www.smashingmagazine.com/2018/09/pwa-angular-6/) for testing. And i use tasks mentioned above to build this test project on my local agent. I also run `ng build --prod` locally. They all generated the right runtime..js file. For troubleshooting could you  build the project locally and check if it generates the right runtime..js file.

Comment: Hey @LeviLu-MSFT yes see it builds correctly locally - but as soon as azure releases the new build something happens and the incorrect file is returned..

Comment: In order to troubleshoot if the problem resides in build pipeline or release pipeline. Could you download the artifacts published to azure devops server from the build pipeline, and check if the runtime.js file generated by build pipeline is correct.

Answer (score 1):

> In The **Begining** there was Hash

A user clicks on home link of your SPA.

Angular served pages as `site.com/#/home`. This was fine as a path. The part after # is never sent to the server. Angular router could read from UrL what route and component to serve.

> The **Change** UseHashingStrategy : false

Then, Angular said we will use `site.com/home` as the path. Instead of direct request to server for file `/home`  angular intercepts it and serves the component. But for this to work Angular router has to be loaded first. Otherwise anyone trying to open `site.com/home` directly would get a 404.

To fix this Angular suggests fallback to index.html by path rewriting on server. In response for pages (`/home`) a 404 candidate, serve the index file so that router can be loaded first and then serve the correct page.

The rewrite rules of your webconfig file is doing just that. After deployment, when html page requests for runtime*.js file, Azure is serving the index.html file....

> This means Azure could not find the file runtime*.js on server. You got fall back index.html

Hope this provides some clue on where to dig next.
My guess is, post deployment when you open index.html it is loaded from cache. Having link to old js file. So, a request for runtime*(old_version)*.js (now deleted after deployment) gives you the fallback file.

Comment: Ah I see, so how would I fix this issue??

Comment: I do not have a clear idea on the fix right now. Can you test by setting expiry headers for the html page alone?  Let us know.

Comment: What headers do I need to apply??